# What are some best practices to mix async libraries with sync code in scala

Tags: scala, future

I'm working on a scala code where a 3rd party library returns a Future[Boolean] object while I need to consume this future object in my scala code which is fully written in a synchronous manner.

Currently, I'm doing Await.result on 3rd party lib operation to ensure it returns just boolean. Is there a better way to handle this, my scala code needs a boolean value for further operation?

Comment: If you can't or do not want to fill your whole code of `Future` and making it asynchronous, then no, there is no better way rather than blocking the thread to wait for the value. At the end of the day, that is what synchronous code would do in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luis noted in the comments, in general there's no alternative to `Await`ing on the `Future`.

That said, you may have some choice about where to `Await`.

For instance, if you have code like

```
val result = Await.result(someFuture, Duration.Inf)
f(result)
```

It may be more useful to run `f` in `Future` land with

```
Await.result(someFuture.map(f), Duration.Inf)
```

If `f` happens to block, then it may be worth either wrapping `f` in `blocking` or explicitly using an `ExecutionContext` which will handle a lot of its threads being blocked (e.g. one that can have more threads than cores) for the `map`.

In general, you'll want to move `Await`s to the outermost edge of your code as you can, even shifting edges if you can.